# Agora.io React-native Classroom and Whiteboard Integration

Tags: react-native, agora.io

I am trying to implement agora classroom and whiteboard in react-native, and I trying to find the best practices to do so and the documentation doesn't help at all. Any advice or tutorial links?

Comment: Which product/repo are you referencing here, can you add the links?

Comment: Is there a tutorial or documentation for building the following features in React-Native:
- Flexible classroom
- ScreenShare
- ScreenRecording
- Whiteboard

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a full demo for the use-case you mentioned, but you can use the [docs](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/react_native/index.html) to build the classroom [demo](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/start_call_react_native?platform=React%20Native) along with [screen sharing](https://github.com/AgoraIO/API-Examples/tree/master/iOS/APIExample/Examples/Advanced/ScreenShare) using native code on iOS and Android. However, Agora doesn't have support for the Whiteboard SDK on React Native as of now.